# jboss. How to determine the concurrent user count along the time?

Tags: java, jboss

Is there some tools to determine the concurrent user count in jboss? The issue is sometimes jboss crashed with outOfMemoryError. And I try to investigate the reason of the error. It would be very helpful to know the concurrent user count along the time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "user", do you mean concurrent access (e.g. EJB calls etc.)? If yes, note that a single "user" might issue several. Doesn't a thread dump or memory dump help you?

Comment: @Thomas There is a jboss portal. As I mentioned above, sometimes jboss crashed with outOfMemoryError. I want to understand if the error occurs after some special count of users accessed to portal (for example, after 20 connection the error erose). Perhaps it`s called concurrent access.. I don`t sure. It would be good if I have some log file of concurrent access along the time (one week, for exaple)

Comment: I don't know JBoss Portal that well but a thread/memory dump should give you a hint on what causes the OutOfMemoryError. That might or might not have to do with the number of users/sessions.

Comment: @Thomas How to make thread dump?

Comment: That depends on the Java version you're using, but as of Java 5+ you should be able to do this using [jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the jmx layer you can know everything about the app server. There are several mbeansthat tells you concurrent ajp requests, http sesions, datasource connections, etc

You can see it online via jmx-console o store an historic value via java melody or jopr or hyperic.